# RDTSC on VisualStudio 2010 Express - C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, rdtsc

I tried to test `rdtsc` on VisualStudio 2010. Heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <intrin.h>
using namespace std;

uint64_t rdtsc()
{
    return __rdtsc();
}

int main()
{
    cout << rdtsc() << "\n";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

But I got errors:

```
------ Build started: Project: test_rdtsc, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  main.cpp
c:\documents and settings\student\desktop\test_rdtsc\test_rdtsc\main.cpp(12): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'rdtsc'
c:\documents and settings\student\desktop\test_rdtsc\test_rdtsc\main.cpp(12): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\documents and settings\student\desktop\test_rdtsc\test_rdtsc\main.cpp(13): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\documents and settings\student\desktop\test_rdtsc\test_rdtsc\main.cpp(14): warning C4244: 'return' : conversion from 'DWORD64' to 'int', possible loss of data
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What should I do? I dont want to change `uint64_t` into `DWORD64`. Why VisualStudio doesnt understand `uint64_t`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `#include <stdint.h>`. Or (better) `#include <cstdint>`.

Visual Studio started shipping those headers with the 2010 version.

Answer (score 2):

To have this working you have to include [`cstdint`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) :

```
#include <cstdint> // Or <stdint.h>
```

`cstdint` is the C++-style version of the C-style header `stdint.h`. Then it is better in your case to use the first one even if both are working in C++.

It is said [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdint.h) that those headers are shipped with visual studio since the 2010 version.

Comment: It is a C++ source file what is being built here. See the initial post that it mentions main.cpp.

Comment: And ? That's why I talk about `<cstdint>` first. I don't understand your point.

Comment: Why do you even mention C then?

Comment: But why when it is a C++ question? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not included stdint.h/cstdint at the top apparently. This will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;

uint64_t rdtsc()
{
    return __rdtsc();
}

int main()
{
    cout << rdtsc() << "\n";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```