# Multiple errors when including Windows Media SDK libs

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to compile a Qt project with msvc2010 which uses the Windows Media SDK 
When I try to include the `wmsbuffer.h` or `wmsdkidl.h` files, I get errors like these:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include\wmsbuffer.h(48) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'INSSBuffer'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include\wmsbuffer.h(48) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include\wmsbuffer.h(48) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'INSSBuffer'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include\wmsbuffer.h(48) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include\wmsbuffer.h(48) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include\wmsbuffer.h(48) : error C2086: 'int INSSBuffer' : redefinition
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include\wmsbuffer.h(48) : see declaration of 'INSSBuffer'
```

I assumed that the problem was that I didn't have the right include or library paths in my .pro file, but even adding this doesn't help:

```
win32 {

    INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Include"
    DEPENDPATH += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Include"

    LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/lib" -lMscvrtd
    LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/lib" -lWmvcore
}
```

The errors also look like something I'd get with circular inclusion, but I haven't found anything else to indicate that this might be the problem here.

Have I forgotten something really obvious?

Comment: Have you looked into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417942/rdtsc-on-visualstudio-2010-express-c-does-not-support-default-int)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that the lines causing errors in `wmsdkidl.h` and `wmsbuffer.h` all look like this:

```
typedef interface IWMMediaProps IWMMediaProps;
```

But the header which defines `interface` (`<objbase.h>`) doesn't seem to be included in `wmsbuffer.h` etc.

Including `objbase.h` in my own header didn't help, so I've solved my problem with this duct-tape solution:

```
#define interface struct
#include <wmsdk.h>
```

Which gets rid of the errors, but generates a lot of warnings due to redefining this keyword...

I'm not entirely sure what is going on or why a library that uses `interface` doesn't include its definition, though, so if someone can offer a better explanation and/or solution, please feel free to!

Comment: Did you include <windows.h> or similar? A lot of header files for subsystems assume you've included that first.

Comment: @JBB I tried including windows.h, but that didn't help. It is included elsewhere in the project though, so I suppose it's not getting included again in this file, causing these problems. I guess it could be good to include all Windows SDK headers in one place to avoid this kind of issues (I haven't had time to try this solution yet). Thanks!